# How to calculate variance over a distribution of time duration proportions

Tags: variance, stochastic-processes

I have events that take a proportion of an observed time slice. The observed variable is the number of events happening at any one moment of time. Therefore the mean is merely the sum of proportions, the minimum is the count at a time where there are the least overlapping.

[image: time series diagram]

In the above diagram we have data that is in terms of start and end times for each 'instance'. We also have the proportion of overlap with the blue box which are the numbers in the table below the diagram. However what we are really trying to calculate are descriptive statistics on the random variable which is the number of instances present at any given time.

My question is, how would I calculate the variation of this kind of dataset?

---

Thinking about this question a bit more, I realize that what I'm actually asking for is help in identifying the distribution that my data falls in. A better visualisation of the distribution above is the following diagram:

[image: diagram 2]

The data is generated by counting for each moment in time the events (above called instances) that are in progress. These start and end randomly. Note that despite appearances the above is not a histogram as the time variable is continuous.

---

Doing some more reading around, it seems that my data could be easily characterised as a [Birth-Death Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth-death_process) as the event count goes up or down depending on events beginning and ending. I still don't see how to calculate the variance however.

Comment: Because your illustration involves multiple kinds of observations ("instances" and "aggregates" as well as min, max, and "avg"), it is unclear what your data really look like. Could you edit your question to provide a specific (short) example of your data?

Comment: @whuber is this clearer?

Comment: @JakubHampl Not really. You say "We also have the proportion of overlap with the blue box which are the numbers in the table below", but there are a lot of numbers there, and an aggregate row with odd min/max. Is the proportion of which you speak the first three rows of the `avg` column?

Comment: @JakubHampl You talk about a number of events per unit time. If these follow a Poisson distribution, then the mean of that distribution $\lambda$ is equal to the variance of that distribution. If the count follow some other discrete distribution (say negative binomial) then there will some other mean variance relationship that you could use. I'm wondering if this is of use to you and your problem?

Comment: +1 for the recent edits--your situation is becoming clearer. It might help to explain how this *stochastic process* is sampled. Do you, for example, count the number of instances present at regular time intervals?  Or do you perhaps detect the start and end of each instance and record their identifiers and times?  And because this is a process, it is likely more will be needed to characterize it than just a few univariate moments like a variance. For instance, one usually would be interested in whether it can be assumed to be stationary and whether the instances are independent.